# Flex DateChooser in chinease and japanease Style

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

How I can change the display of Month and Year display to Japanese style (i.e. Year Month) as in Header of Flex DateField. What I would like to convert the style July　2011年　to 2011年　7月.[![enter image description here][1]][2]
How can we change the calender header format ?
i have used DateField in flex.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
-locale=ja_JP
```

If you're using Flash Builder, write it below.
Project > Properties > Flex Compiler > Additional Compiler Arguments

If you want to change Japanese Style dynamically, set the locale both English and Japanese.

```
-locale=en_US,ja_JP
```

and can change dymamically like this.

```
private var resource: IResourceManager = ResourceManager.getInstance();
private function changeLocale(): void{
    if (user selected JP){
        resource.localeChain = ["ja_JP"];
    }else{
        resource.localeChain = ["en_US"];
    }
    resource.update();
}
```

Comment: What SDK are you using?
I'm using 4.6.0 and worked fine.